# How do you send a post request of a sliders value as its changing in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app which should receive the value of a slider in index.html constantly but i'm not sure how to access the variable in the flask file.

The app.py flask file:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))

@app.route('/index', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        current = request.form['current']
        print(current)
        return render_template('index.html')

    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

The html file:

```
<body>
    <form method = 'POST'>
    <div class="rangeslider"> 
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="myslider" id="sliderRange"> 
        <p>
            <span id="demo"></span>
        </p> 
    </div> 
        
        <script> 
            const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var rangeslider = document.getElementById("sliderRange"); 
            var output = document.getElementById("demo"); 
            var current;
                        
            rangeslider.oninput = function() {
                current = this.value;
                
                if (current < 33){
                    output.innerHTML = 'Reverse';
                    current = 'reverse'
                    }
                else if (current >= 33 && current <= 66){
                    output.innerHTML = 'Neutral';
                    current = 'neutral'  
                }
                else if (current > 66){
                    output.innerHTML = 'Drive';
                    current = 'drive'
                }
            }

        </script> 


    </form>
</body>
```

I've tried a lot of different things so some things in the code might be left over from those attempts but the basic question is, how do I access that html variable current in my python file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make a call to the server, where you will be processing this value (and possibly do something with it on the server, then return it to the browser, where you might display it somehow).

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))

@app.route('/index', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        current = request.form['current']
        print(current)
        return render_template('index.html')

    return render_template('index.html')

# I've added this method to receive slider updates
@app.route('/slider_update', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def slider():
    received_data = request.data
    print(received_data)
    return received_data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

And here is the call to the server.

```html
<body>
    <form method = 'POST'>
    <div class="rangeslider"> 
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="myslider" id="sliderRange"> 
        <p>
            <span id="demo"></span>
        </p> 
    </div> 
        
        <script> 
            const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var rangeslider = document.getElementById("sliderRange"); 
            var output = document.getElementById("demo"); 
            var current;
                        
            rangeslider.oninput = function() {
                current = this.value;
                
                if (current < 33){
                    output.innerHTML = 'Reverse';
                    current = 'reverse'
                    }
                else if (current >= 33 && current <= 66){
                    output.innerHTML = 'Neutral';
                    current = 'neutral'  
                }
                else if (current > 66){
                    output.innerHTML = 'Drive';
                    current = 'drive'
                }
            
                // I've added this call to the server, which send 'current' value
                Http.open('POST', '/slider_update')
                Http.send(current)

            }

        </script> 


    </form>
</body>
```

You'll see values printed in the server log.